# JFrame Components Not Appearing

Tags: java, swing

I am very new to Java and I'm trying to put together a simple time calculator.

How come the add() method only throws up the last thing I added?  When I run the program it only shows "Days" instead of the textboxes and the years label.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class TimeCalculator extends JFrame

{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      JOptionPaneMultiInput window = new JOptionPaneMultiInput();
      window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      window.setSize(300,500);
      window.setVisible(true);
    }

      public TimeCalculator()
    {
      super("Time Calculator");

        JTextField yearsField = new JTextField(5);
        JTextField daysField = new JTextField(5);
        JTextField hoursField = new JTextField(5);
        JTextField minutesField = new JTextField(5);
        JTextField secondsField = new JTextField(5);

        JLabel yearsLabel = new JLabel();
        JLabel daysLabel = new JLabel();
        JLabel hoursLabel = new JLabel();
        JLabel minutesLabel = new JLabel();
        JLabel secondsLabel = new JLabel();

        JCheckBox yearsCheckbox = new JCheckBox();
        JCheckBox daysCheckbox = new JCheckBox();
        JCheckBox hoursCheckbox = new JCheckBox();
        JCheckBox minutesCheckbox = new JCheckBox();
        JCheckBox secondsCheckbox = new JCheckBox();

        JLabel yearsCLabel = new JLabel();
        JLabel daysCLabel = new JLabel();
        JLabel hoursCLabel = new JLabel();
        JLabel minutesCLabel = new JLabel();
        JLabel secondsCLabel = new JLabel();

        JButton convertButton = new JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        yearsLabel.setText("Years");
        daysLabel.setText("Days");
        hoursLabel.setText("Hours");
        minutesLabel.setText("Minutes");
        secondsLabel.setText("Seconds");

        yearsCLabel.setText("Yr");
        daysCLabel.setText("D");
        hoursCLabel.setText("Hr");
        minutesCLabel.setText("Min");
        secondsCLabel.setText("Sec");

        convertButton.setText("Convert");
        convertButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
                {
                    //doConvert(evt); this will be added later once i figure everything out
                }
            });


            add(yearsField);
            add(yearsLabel);
            add(daysField);
            add(daysLabel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using a `LayoutManager`, perhaps a `GridLayout`.

Comment: I think they are overlapping.

Answer (score 3):

`JOptionPaneMultiInput` mentioned in `main()` is not part of the posted source code. Consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

The answer to:

> When I run the program it only shows "Days" instead of the textboxes
>   and the years label.

`TimeCalculator` that appears in the question extends `JFrame`. By default `JFrame` uses `BorderLayout` layout. When `BorderLayout` is used, `add()` method without constraints argument results in `BorderLayout.CENTER` constraint to add components. So you add your objects to the center of `BorderLayout`. Every subsequent add() replaces the previous component that was added. At the end, only `daysLabel` remains.

See [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more details. Also see [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for other layout managers as you have many controls in your frame and it would be hard to lay it out without additional nesting panels.